# How to assemble sphere with cylinder opengl es

Tags: opengl-es, collision

I am working now in opengl es and drawing sphere with cylinder textured.  When I draw these primitives one of them overwhelming another and they cannot meet in the same coordinates to meet each other. Explain the concept of assembling or colliding primitives in opengl es.

Comment: Are you drawing a textured sphere and a cylinder, or a sphere with cylindrical texturing? Also, OpenGL (ES) does not do collision detection of any kind. It draws primitives (triangles) as you tell it. If you want any such thing as collision, you must do it yourself.

Comment: thank you Damon for quick reply. i am drawing textured sphere and a textured cylinder. I was trying to get the distance between them and collide, but the question is what distance do you take normally for cylinder and sphere. Center of sphere and a "center" of cylinder?

Comment: I'd rather take the two endpoints of the cylinder, but you can also take the middle point (will then need a length and radius for the cylinder). Colliding cylinders and spheres _looks_ very easy (as in, two dot products, and comparing a radius) but if you want it to be failsafe, it's surprisingly hard with a lot of special cases.

Comment: You know. I have use the following method to detect whether both collide. I was rotating cylinder along z axis and sphere being static in its own 3d space. By changing the height of cylinder to the highest in order to touch the sphere I was expecting the cylinder overwhelm the sphere, but nothing like this happened. I was also moving both sphere and cylinder being one of them static along z axis but none of either points collided another. what effect should you expect when you moving one object and then that object "crashes" another one?